# C# WebSockets Client to MVC Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket

I have an API controller that creates a web socket connection and can connect and interact with fine when using JavaScript, but I'd also like to be able to connect to it using a C# client. I've tried a few different libraries (Alchemy, WebSocket4Net, and WebSocket-Sharp), and they all seem to be timing out during connection open.

Here's the code for the server side:

```cs
class WsController : ApiController
{
  public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
  {
    HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new WsHandler(id));
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
  }

  internal class WsHandler : WebSocketHandler
  {
    public WsHandler(string id) { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

If I'm using a JS client, I can use `var ws = new WebSocket(url + "?id=someid");` to connect and then send and receive messages. When using a C# client, I get stuck during the handshake and the connect times out. Here's some example code using WebSocket4Net.

```
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
ws.Opened += new EventHandler(ws_Connect);
ws.Closed += new EventHandler(ws_Disconnect);
ws.Error += new EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs>(ws_Error);
ws.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(ws_Receive);
ws.Open(); // Timeout on this line. No errors are thrown to ws_Error.
```

Is there another way to create a websocket server using MVC's `ApiController`?

Comment: Wouldn't [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) be able to handle this?